# Summarizing a dictionary of arrays in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, arrays, dictionary

I got the following dictionary:

```
mydict = {
  'foo': [1,19,2,3,24,52,2,6],          # sum: 109
  'bar': [50,5,9,7,66,3,2,44],          # sum: 186
  'another': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],         # sum:  36
  'entry': [0,0,0,2,99,4,33,55],        # sum: 193
  'onemore': [21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28]  # sum: 196
}
```

I need to efficiently filter out and sort the top x entries by the sum of the array.

For example, the **Top 3 sorted** and **filtered** list for the example above would be

```
sorted_filtered_dict = {
  'onemore': [21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28], # sum: 196
  'entry': [0,0,0,2,99,4,33,55],        # sum: 193
  'bar': [50,5,9,7,66,3,2,44]           # sum: 186
}
```

I'm fairly new to Python, and tried it myself with chaining a sum and filter function on a lambda function, but struggled with the actual syntax.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's easy to do with a sort:

```
sorted(mydict.iteritems(), key=lambda tup: sum(tup[1]), reverse=True)[:3]
```

This is reasonable if the ratio is similar to this one (3 / 5).  If it's larger, you'll want to avoid the sort (O(n log n)), since top 3 can be done in O(n).  For instance, using [heapq](http://docs.python.org/library/heapq.html), the heap module:

```
heapq.nlargest(3, mydict.iteritems(), key=lambda tup: sum(tup[1]))
```

This is O(n + 3 log n), since assembly the initial heap is O(n) and re-heapifying is O(log n).

EDIT: If you're using Python 2.7 or later, you can easily convert to a [`OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) ([equivalent version](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576693/) for Python 2.4+):

```
OrderedDict(heapq.nlargest(3, mydict.iteritems(), key=lambda tup: sum(tup[1])))
```

`OrderedDict` has the same API as `dict`, but remembers insertion order.

Comment: How do you get O(n + 3 log n), it should be O(n log k), or when k = 3 the constant cancels out and you'll get O(n)

Comment: In my real world example, it's rather the top 100 out of a couple hundred thousand, therefore the heapq example is probably to be preferred. Thanks.

Comment: Just realized that this doesn't give me a dictionary but an array of arrays. Any ideas?

Comment: @Ants, can you explain how you calculate that?  Wikipedia [gives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm#Language_support) O(n + k log n), and I think that checks out, based on the reason I explained in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

For such a small slice it's not worth using islice

```
sorted(mydict.iteritems(), key=lambda (k,v): sum(v), reverse=True)[:3]
```